# how to get the Process Description from the os process list?

Tags: python

i'm using psutil to get a list of process information such as name and pid.

```
import psutil
for i in psutil.process_iter(['name','ppid','pid']):
    print(i.info)
```

Any way to get the Process Description instead of the name?

[image: attached image for clarificaition]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly by the "FileDescription" - do you mean you want to know the path of the main executable for the process?

Comment: Apparently you're after the "Process Description" instead of the 'FileDescription' now, but where are you seeing this Process Description you're after?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "Process Description"? Please give an example

Comment: I think OP is referring to a description that shows up in Windows's Task Manager for some processes.

Comment: added screenshots for clarification. I'm after Description for respective application

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing labelled "process description" in the [available attributes](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.as_dict) for a  `Process.as_dict()`, which is the information that `process_iter` returns.

The best thing that maps to a description is probably the `exe` attribute, which contains the absolute path to the executable (when available).